# ReflectionException Class Home does not exist Codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I had installed the fresh Codeigniter4 with `public const CI_VERSION = '4.1.9';`, and configured the basic steps

**Step 1**

```
app > app.php > public $baseURL = 'http://121.52.xxx.xxx/faculty_portal/';
removed index.php from $indexPage='';
public $uriProtocol = 'PATH_INFO';
```

**Step 2**

.env file renamed and set the development mode

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

**Step 3**

from public folder > moved index.php and .htaccess file to main folder

```
.htaccess file has default configuration
```

whereas the index.php file

```
$pathsConfig = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
require realpath($pathsConfig) ?: $pathsConfig;
$paths = new Config\Paths();
$bootstrap = rtrim($paths->systemDirectory, '\\/ ') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php';
```

Error Images are attached here.

[image]
[image]

I am trying to install it in **subfolder that is faculty_portal**.
Respected community please guide me where I am doing wrong. You guidance/help will be  highly appreciated.

**-------------------------------------Question Updated-------------------------------------**

**Routes Code**

```
namespace Config;
$routes = Services::routes();

if (file_exists(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php')) {
    require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);


$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/test', 'Home::test');


if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php')) {
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

Here I want to access the /test route

with the url access of `http://121.52.XXX.XXX/faculty_portal/public/test`

**Home Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home_view');
    }

    public function test(){
        echo "hello";exit;
    }

}
```

The **index.php** file in public folder

```
$minPhpVersion = '7.4'; // If you update this, don't forget to update `spark`.
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, $minPhpVersion, '<')) {
    $message = sprintf(
        'Your PHP version must be %s or higher to run CodeIgniter. Current version: %s',
        $minPhpVersion,
        PHP_VERSION
    );

    exit($message);
}

define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

chdir(FCPATH);
require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
$paths = new Config\Paths();
require rtrim($paths->systemDirectory, '\\/ ') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php';

require_once SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/DotEnv.php';
(new CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv(ROOTPATH))->load();
$app = Config\Services::codeigniter();
$app->initialize();
$context = is_cli() ? 'php-cli' : 'web';
$app->setContext($context);
$app->run();
```

Here is the error message looks like

[image]
[image]

Comment: @codeigniter4 #codeigniter4 any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the [v4.2.1]
You don't need to move index.php in main directory. Keep it in public folder.

And line 20 in index.php must be

```
require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

For App -> Config -> App.php

```
public $uriProtocol = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

For App -> Config -> Routes.php

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);
```

For App -> Config -> Feature.php

```
 public bool $autoRoutesImproved = true;
```

For .htaccess in main directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

For the public folder .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|doc|data|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I had followed all steps you mentioned. It's still not working for me. for sitename.com I entered the http://121.52.xx9.xxx/ IP address of VPS. See the error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnUn4.png

Comment: remove both line in both .htacsess `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$` and `RewriteRule (.*) https://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L] `

Comment: After removing this only the home page is working that is `Url is : http://121.52.xx9.xxx/faculty_portal/public/`. The rest of the pages are not working. `Url is : http://121.52.xx9.xxx/faculty_portal/public/test`. test is defined in the route.

Comment: can you share some code of your about routes, controller or model etc.

Comment: I had updated the question please have a look now.

Comment: where is your `/public/` url in the route?. remove `/public/` in your address bar or define in route like `$routes->get('/public/test', 'Home::test');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247216/discussion-between-nomanjaved-and-starlings).

Comment: `public $uriProtocol = 'REQUEST_URI';` solved my issue